# Light Powered Motor Troubles

Tags: current, digital

I'm working on a small car (<1 kg) which will drive when there is light and stop when there isn't. Below is a plan with code drawn up (the only numbers I know for sure are the current gains for the TIP31C transistor and the rated load current of the 6 V motor I'm using). I'm going to map the analog voltages to a digital signal output.

I read that the maximum digital output was 40 mA and also that `analogWrite` gives a pulse width modulation (PWM) which can be set to 100% (255) [the code: `outputval/1`], 50% (127) [the code: `outputval/2`]. I'm concerned with the lack of control I have here over the current. Will Arduino by default draw 7.75 mA maximum if the input signal is high [giving the output signal also as high]? If not, can I control the current in this manner reliably? Also are there anything I should worry about if I added another 6 V motor in parallel? Coding and electrical suggestions greatly welcomed.

TIP31 transistor: http://www.hobbytronics.co.uk/datasheets/TIP31.pdf

6 V dc motor: http://www.kysanelectronics.com/graphics/RF-370CA-22170.pdf

maximum digital output: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/DigitalPins

PWM: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/PWM

[image: the plan]

The code:

```
const int transistorbase = 9;
void setup() {
  //set the base as digital output:
  pinMode(transistorbase, OUTPUT);
}
void loop() {
  //read voltage at divider:
  int inputval=analogRead(A0);
  //map voltage to digital
  int outputval=map(inputval,0,1023,0,255); 
  //control transistor:
  analogWrite(transistorbase,outputval);
}
```

tl;dr
Codewise, how do I control the digital output current to my needs? Am I seeing ghosts?

Comment: You should seriously consider using an FET for motor control rather than a bipolar or darlington transistor.  Most Arduion hobbyists use IC-based drivers, but the same concern applies there as it does to discretes - seek FET, avoid bipolar.

Comment: I just read up on them. Will that fix my worries about current because it has a stronger response to voltage (seeing as a strong output signal will nearly be 5V for a fast PWM frequency) i.e. it is a device controlled by electric field and not a current requirement? Would this be a suitable FET, I don't think I'll fry it at VGS of 20 V, and assuming the PWM wave gives an average above 2 V above the VGS(th), it'll close when the input signal is weak, right?

Comment: https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/irfz44npbf.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a40153563b3a9f220d

Comment: No, the threshold voltage is too high, it will be only barely on when driven by an Arduino.  Most suitable parts are surface mount only but https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/irlb8721pbf.pdf might work to a degree

Comment: So the digital output is not nearly 5V? That's what I got from the PWM reading.

Comment: An FET's threshold voltage is where it just begins to turn on.  You want something much higher for good performance.  Try to find one with a threshold below 2v.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would take a simple n-channel MOSFET like [this one](https://www.mouser.com/ds/2/308/BUZ11-1118746.pdf). At 5V on the gate it can drive up to 8A (so you have plenty of space to connect other motors as long as your power source can handle this) and because it is a MOSFET you don't have to draw much current from the Arduino (only enough to load the gate of the MOSFET). You can also hold the current under the critical value for your motor with a simple resistor (fit for the resulting power dissipation) in series.

Yes, the output of the PWM is 5V - the operation voltage of the Arduino. The whole point in PWM is to use only the digital values (here 0V and 5V) and varying so fast, that slow systems as the motor cannot follow this motion, but summing over the impulses. So the motor gets only very fast kicks. And for a normal motor you don't need fast PWM. This only increases the frequency response from the MOSFET.

The code seems for to me.

Comment: That is not a very good MOSFET to use with this, as its threshold voltage is high enough that an Arduino will only barely turn it on.  You want one with a lower threshold voltage so that a ~5v output can turn it more completely on.